# Cocos2d: CCSpriteBatchNode grandchildren z-order displaying in wrong order

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I thought I understood how z order works in cocos2d, but I'm having an issue I can't explain.

I have a number of CCSprites as children of a CCSpriteBatchNode, created with the code below.  Each of these sprites has several children CCSprites.  Everything works fine as long as the z values I pass to addChild are positive.  When they are negative, it stops working as I expect, and I can't find any information about why this could be the case.  I am using cocos2d version 1.0.1.

```
    CCSprite *pikaSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"PikaLarge.png"];
    [pikaSprite setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.0f, 0.5f)];
    [pikaSprite setPosition:ccp(pikaX, pikaBox.boundingBox.size.height * 0.6f)];            
    [pikaBatchNode addChild:pikaSprite z:0];

    CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Sprite1.png"];
    [sprite1 setPosition:ccp(pikaSprite.boundingBox.size.width * 0.7f, pikaSprite.boundingBox.size.height * 0.9f)];
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite1 z:-1];

    CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Sprite2.png"];
    [sprite2 setPosition:ccp(pikaSprite.boundingBox.size.width * 0.8f, pikaSprite.boundingBox.size.height * 0.9f)];

    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite2 z:-10];
```

sprite2 appears in front of sprite1, but behind pikaSprite.  As I understand it, it should be behind sprite1, because they are siblings and sprite2 has a lower z value.

I want sprite2 to be behind sprite1, both behind pikaSprite, which I can't get unless I change the order I add them, which is possible, but somewhat more difficult.

I've tried four different orderings, this is the only one that doesn't work.

1.

```
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite1 z:1];
    ...
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite2 z:10];  // sprite2 is in front, correct
```

2.

```
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite1 z:10];  // sprite1 is in front, correct
    ...
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite2 z:1];
```

3.

```
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite1 z:-10];
    ...
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite2 z:-1];  // sprite2 is in front, correct
```

4.

```
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite1 z:-1];
    ...
    [pikaSprite addChild:sprite2 z:-10];  // sprite2 is in front - ???
```

When they are negative, it seems the last one added is always in front.

It would be possible to rewrite things to deal with this, but I'm very curious why this is happening and wondering if I might be misunderstanding something.

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Comment: Just a hunch: try with sprite1 z=0 and sprite2 z=-10, is that correct or is sprite2 still in front of sprite1?

Comment: That comes out correct, though if I add another negative z sprite, the negative ones come out backwards.  I poked around in CCSpriteBatchNode.m and made some changes that seem to fix it.  I'm not sure if this version of cocos2d is still being worked on, so I'm not sure if I should do anything with this.  I'd be happy to post what I did if anyone is interested.